# Porting issues in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: porting-ubuntu-touch

I have downloaded the sources for ubuntu touch which was around 21gb.

But whenever i use the `make -j4` command, after sometime of compiling, it always says that i'm missing something or the other...

I have been including manually the files which are missing and it seems never ending. Every time something pops up.

Can you guys tell me if there are a set of tools i require to build the ROM? And if  there is, can you tell me where can i find all of them?
Like in one package to have all files i need so that i can have uninterrupted compilation?

Comment: _it always says that i'm missing something or the other..._ Could you post actual error messages (as text, please)?

Comment: now its saying this "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL"